# Displaying Multiple Images after User Request on Android

Tags: android

So the idea is that a user presses a button, an image is fetched and then displayed on screen. This happens multiple times, so the second image is displayed under the first one under the same parent XML tag, and so on. I have a `ScrollView` XML tag that handles the browsing of the images and I am unsure about the type of view I should put under it.

I have taken care to set the visibility on at the end of configuring every `ImageView` and everything, but it doesn't work. Nothing seems to be working and I am getting no errors when testing, so could somebody provide an example so I could start from scratch?
Thank you.

Code after request:

```
public void addImage(int i /* index for object from collection*/){
        image CurrImg; //image is the object
        CurrImg = (image)images.get(i); //images is a collection
        ImageView img;
        img = new ImageView(Screwl.getContext()); //Screwl is the scroll view
        img.setImageBitmap(CurrImg.getNewBmp());
        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

What happens is I press the button, and simply nothing happens on-screen. Every time I press the button the available RAM goes down in the device monitor, so the fetching of the image works.

Comment: What does _but it doesn't work. Nothing seems to be working and I am getting no errors when testing_ mean? Please, provide your code

Comment: @il_raffa I just did. Tell me if you need anything more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach your ImageView to something for display.  If `Screwl` is a ScrollView you can do:

```
Screwl.removeAllViews();
Screwl.addView(img);
```

Better yet, create one inside the scrollview in your layout XML and reuse that one:

```
img = Screwl.findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);  // instead of 'new'
```

Comment: I have multiple ImageView objects to display. That is why I am not going through XML and I will not be adding the removeAllViews command. I tried to do the addView, but still, nothing happens.

Comment: ScrollView can have only one child.  Try addView into a LinearLayout or some other multi-view container?

Comment: I did, I tried both a relative layout and a linear one (both vertical).